Rendered Event triggering twice while Embedding the powerbi report
We're embedding the powerbi report using "powerbi-client". Here is the application code we're using to Embed the report.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/powerbi-client@2.23.1/dist/powerbi.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>PowerBI Embedded Sample</h1>
    <div id="embedContainer" style="height: 80vh;"></div>
</body>
<script>
    var config = {
        type: "report",
        tokenType: 0,
        accessToken: '',
        embedUrl: '',
        id: '',
        permissions: 7,
        settings: {
            filterPaneEnabled: true,
            navContentPaneEnabled: true,
            visualRenderedEvents: true
        }
    }

        report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, config);

        // report.off removes all event handlers for a specific event
        report.off("loaded");
        report.off("rendered");


        // report.on will add an event handler
        report.on("loaded", function () {
            console.log("loaded")
            report.off("loaded");
        });

        // report.off removes all event handlers for a specific event
        report.off("error");

        report.on("error", function (event) {
            console.log(event.detail);
        });

        // report.on will add an event handler
        let i = 0;
        report.on("rendered", function () {
            // renderedResolve();
            console.log("Rendered event", i++, " ", Date.now());
        });

        report.on("visualRendered",async ()=>{
          console.log("Visual rendered");
        })
    }

    embedPowerBIReport();


</script>

</html>

When the report gets embedded we're getting the rendered event triggered twice.Does the rendered event should be triggered once all the visuals are rendered ? We're expecting this behavior.
When we use the same code in Developer sandbox we're not experiencing this issue.We used the sample Report from doc.
Here is the snapshot where we're getting rendered event calling twice in console log.
Snaspsot
Could anyone please look into this and help us to figure out why the rendered event is getting triggered twice. We're expecting that rendered event should trigger only once when all the visuals are rendered.

Able to repro the issue and MSFT confirmed it was a bug from their side. Will follow the progress and update it here.
